# How to avoid connection errors to an api in flutter? (breakpoint type appears in VS code)

Tags: flutter

I am purposely causing this error.

[image]

```
  var response = await http.post(url,headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},body: args); //die here
  //not continues
  print(response);
```

I have turned off the execution of my server, so the web request cannot be executed. I want to know how I can control this error, since the application dies at this point.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch an exception, you need to wrap the line that causes it with a try/catch block :

```
try {
   var response = http.post(url);
}
catch(exception){
  print(exception);
}
```